# How to make post sticky in the admin page?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-admin, sticky-post

i work with restaurant plugin that use custom post type.
the question is, if it possible to select some post and make him sticky (always be in the top) in the admin?
i need this because when you add many items to the restaurant menu, it becomes hard to find the items(posts).

so i just looking for solution to find post from post type by slug, and make him sticky in the admin page (not in the front)

i made code that find the right post, but how make him to be sticky?

```
        $test = get_page_by_path( 'slug', $output = OBJECT, $post_type = 'post-type' );
        $test_id = $test->ID;
        $test_page = get_post($test_id);
        $test_title = apply_filters('the_title', $test_page->post_title);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### "Admin Stickies" for custom post types:

To support sticky custom posts in the backend, you can use the following code snippet in your `functions.php` file in the current theme directory or in your custom plugin:

```
/**
 * Set admin stickies for the 'foodmenu' custom post type 
 */
add_action( 'init', function() {
    if( function_exists( 'wpse_cpt_stickies' ) )
        wpse_cpt_stickies( $cpt = 'foodmenu', $ids = array( 53, 102, 23 ) );
});
```

where you can adjust the `$cpt` and `$ids` to your needs.

We could also create a custom meta field, e.g. `is_admin_sticky` for these admin sticky cpt posts. Then we can fetch them all with:

```
/**
 * Set admin stickies for the 'foodmenu' custom post type 
 */
add_action( 'init', function() {
    if( function_exists( 'wpse_cpt_stickies' ) )
    {
       // Fetch all sticky posts with the "is_admin_sticky=1" custom field:
       $ids = get_posts( 
           array( 
               'post_type'      => 'foodmenu', 
               'meta_key'       => 'is_admin_sticky',
               'meta_value'     => '1',
               'posts_per_page' => 5,    # <-- Modify this to your needs
           )
       ); 

    wpse_cpt_stickies( $cpt = 'foodmenu', $ids );
});
```

### The "Admin Stickies" demo plugin:

We use the following plugin to support this:

```
<?php   
/**
 * Plugin Name:   Admin Stickies for custom post types
 * Plugin URI:    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167371/26350
 * Plugin Author: birgire
 * Version:       0.0.1
 */

function wpse_cpt_stickies( $cpt, $ids )
{
    $stickies = new WPSE_CPT_Admin_Stickies;
    $stickies->init( $cpt, $ids );
}

class WPSE_CPT_Admin_Stickies
{
    private $cpt;
    private $ids;

    public function init( $cpt = 'post' , $ids = array() )
    {
        $this->cpt = $cpt;
        $this->ids = $ids;
        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array( $this, 'pre_get_posts' ) );
    }

    public function pre_get_posts( $q )
    {
        if( 
            is_admin() 
            && 'edit.php' === $GLOBALS['pagenow']
            && $q->is_main_query() 
            && $this->cpt === $q->get( 'post_type' )
        )
        {
            add_filter( 'post_class', array( $this, 'post_class' ), 10, 3 );    
            add_filter( 'option_sticky_posts', array( $this, 'custom_stickies' ) );
            $q->is_home = 1; # <-- We must use this "hack" to support sticky posts
            $q->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', 0 );
        } 
    }

    public function custom_stickies( $data )
    {
        // remove_filter( current_filter(), array( $this, __FUNCTION__ ) );
        if( count( $this->ids ) > 0 )
            $data = $this->ids;

        return $data;
    }

    public function post_class( $classes, $class, $post_ID ) 
    {
        // Append the sticky CSS class to the corresponding row:
        if( in_array( $post_ID, $this->ids, true ) )
            $classes[] = 'is-admin-sticky';

        return $classes;
    }

} // end class
```

The sticky posts are saved into the `sticky_posts` option and it's only available for normal posts.

Here we hijack the `option_sticky_posts` filter to support this for custom post types in the back-end.

If we don't remove our `option_sticky_posts` filter callback, after the first run, then it will also affect the `is_sticky()` function. Then we will get the native `sticky` CSS class in the table row. Therefore I've commented out the filter removal.

We can also use the `post_class` filter to add our custom `is-admin-sticky` CSS class to the corresponding table row.

This demo could be extended further to support the front-end, maybe with the third input parameter:

```
wpse_cpt_stickies( $cpt, $ids, $context );
```

where `$context` could be `'front'`, `'back'` or `'both'`.

Comment: Hello @birgire and thanks for the code and explanation. what i dont get is how i can use my code that find the right post by slug in: get( 'post_type' ).

Comment: Hi @need-help. I'm not sure I follow you there ;-) Do you want to set the sticky posts programmatically, based on their slugs? Where are you using this code snippet?

Comment: Hello @birgire yes that what i want. for example i have item named crazy steak, and the slug is crazy-steak, so this one i want to make sticky.

Comment: But you can always do it manually ;-) so that's not an option?

Comment: Hi @birgire to do this manually i need to use some plugin to make Sticky post work in the Custom Post Types. i think if there is some other option without using any plugin it will be better.

Comment: aha ok you're using a custom post type, then I understand your problems better. Let me try to figure a way around that ...

Comment: Hopefully you can use this demo plugin, but currently you have to use the post ids to select the sticky posts.

Comment: Hi @birgire thank you very much! if you could add the support for the slug it will be awesome! i need this because i use this in multisite and the item id will be different on each blog. but the slug will stay the same because i dont allow to change the slug in multisite.

Comment: You could of course use your `get_page_by_path()` to fetch the corresponding id by a given slug. But you could also create a custom meta field `is_admin_sticky` for these custom posts and then fetch them all with `get_posts()`. I updated the answer to give an example.

Comment: Hi @birgire i use my code to get the slug and then i get the id by slug to use in the function. so all works great! just one little question. how can i add some css class to sticky item?

Comment: I updated the answer, so now the corresponding sticky row get's the `is-admin-sticky` CSS class.

Comment: Finally, the native `sticky` CSS class should now be usable, after the last update, because we override the `is_sticky()` check as well.